# Grow a Diagonal Arrow in Powerpoint

Tags: animation, powerpoint, presentation

On my slide I have a map of the South during the Civil War. I want to place a thick arrow pointing to Atlanta from the Northwest. I then want to create an animation where the arrow moves Southeast towards Savannah over the period of a few seconds, with the rear of the arrow remaining where it started, and the head of arrow proceeding Southeast as I described. The point is to illustrate Sherman's March to the Sea.

I seem to be able to move the arrow using a motion path, but I seemingly can't grow the arrow in any other way than horizontal or vertical (not diagonally). I also tried adding a rectangle object, and adding a wipe entrance effect, but wipe seems again to only allow its effect to happen from 90 degree angles.

Can anybody help me figure out what should be a seemingly easy task? I am using Powerpoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use *multiple* arrows with different lengths and the animation feature. First make all the arrows invisible.

```
1. Make the 1st arrow appear with a left click trigger. This becomes the *current* arrow.
2. After the required delay, make the *current* arrow disappear while making the *next* arrow appear.
3. Repeat step #2 above until done.
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your background, this might work. Put a box over the diagonal arrow the same color as the background, without boarders. Now animate the box with a motion path to the southeast, allowing your arrow to be revealed. If the box is an issue, combine the motion path with a wipe disappear from west to east, on a 0.25 to 0.5 second delay.